# Is there a way to create a legal description, or some kind of description of a shapefile?

Tags: cogo, metes-and-bounds, parcel-fabric, legal-description

A colleague and I are working on creating legal descriptions for several hundred districts, for which we already have shapefiles. I'm wondering if there's a way to use COGO to help provide a description of the outline of it?

I'm fairly certain it's going to use parcel fabrics, and/or a model.

Comment: This is somewhat open-ended, but I'd try using Python and the Arcpy Geometry tools. Each polygon part is a list of Point objects, and you could extract the X and Y coordinates of each point, and then try and figure the distance and direction from the previous point, essentially a COGO in reverse, and output the distance and direction to a text file or something. But you would have to talk to your lawyers and see if that meets the requirement of a legal description.

Comment: Honestly, anything would meet the definition, it's archaic and everybody uses the shapefiles anyhow. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Yes, you can *help* write your descriptions using COGO tools - no parcel fabric required, though that can also be used. I've voted to close this as a duplicate where I answered how (if ruled not to be a dupe, I'll add a more detailed answer here). Note that it doesn't give you the language per se, just the bearings and distances for the calls. You'd have to take those results and do some editing to insert phrases like 'thence' or measurement units or whatever to get it to read the way you want. You'd also have to work out your point of beginnings and commencement calls.